# What is an affline manifold? How do check if a space (?) is affline manifold. Is it related to vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, differential-topology

I have no idea about differential geometry or topology because I am engineer. I need the conditons to check the applicability of a theorem to particular case.From my search I could only find a wiki page (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Affine_manifold#/Formal_definition) which isn't very helpful is providing insight nor sufficient conditions to check if a space is affline manifold. 
Thanks !

Comment: Can you tell us what the theorem is and where you want to apply it instead? I think that would be easier than describing what an affine manifold is.

Comment: Referring to theorem 3 (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10898-012-9917-0). It establishes strong duality for a class on nonconvex quadratic programs when the variables to be optimized belong to an affline manifold in n-dimensional space of real numbers. So my question is if the variables are bounded by linear equalities and ineqaulities, is that region a affline manifold ?

Comment: Yes, it is. No need to learn what affine manifolds are in general.

Comment: Thanks ! Also what does a parallel subspace to the the affline manifold mean? What will be its properties and required conditions for a  vector to belong to this space?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is it still an affine manifold if I we consider the space to be bounded by non-negativity constraints i.e. $x \geq 0$ ?